# Facebook Integration with Libgdx java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: libgdx

I am following this https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook/wiki/3.-Setup-gdx-facebook to study how to link between libgdx game with facebook.

I only add dependencies in core and android because I wants to build an Android game. However, after adding dependencies at :core side, i get this error when running it on desktop.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.getBackBufferWidth()I
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.getBackBufferWidth()I
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.HdpiUtils.glViewport(HdpiUtils.java:44)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport.apply(Viewport.java:49)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScalingViewport.update(ScalingViewport.java:62)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport.update(Viewport.java:58)
        at Screen.SplashScreen.resize(SplashScreen.java:57)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
        at com.bobiz.game.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:22)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

I don't understand what cause this error. It works fine if I build it in Android.

Please help... I am still beginner to Libgdx.

My gradle file codes:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.8.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "BreakEmAll"
        gdxVersion = '1.7.0'
        roboVMVersion = '1.8.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.6.0'
        aiVersion = '1.6.0'
        gdxFacebookVersion = '1.4.1'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }

}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile group: 'com.restfb', name: 'restfb', version: '2.9.0'
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile group: 'com.restfb', name: 'restfb', version: '2.9.0'
        compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-android:1.4.1"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile group: 'com.restfb', name: 'restfb', version: '2.9.0'
        compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-core:1.4.1"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: Apart from `gdxfacebook`, all artifact version are quite old so please update all of them and sync

Comment: Thanks. After update my libgdx, it works smooth now.